# Making sure that the function I am using returns the correct kind of values in haskell. (i.e does not contain an `error ""` or similar)

Tags: haskell, proof, proof-of-correctness

Haskell is often touted as the language to do proofs in. (Before they start recomnding Agda, Idris or Coq).
However, is this piece of code not potentially problematic or am I understanding the concept wrong?

```hs
x :: Int -> Int
x n
 | x == 0 = error "Error"
 | otherwise = n + 1
```

As far as I understand this is not very good for checking proofs(since returning `Int` is not mandatory here.)
**Is there a way we could solve this?**

As far as I understand, the other aforementioned languages avoid this.[1] I do not understand how. **Is it simply because of the stricter type-system or some other guarantee provided by the language?**

So far I have looked at the language documentations at a high level but found nothing.

[1] = https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/9toh6b/comment/e8y4gzi/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: `error "Error"` here has type `Int`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Forgive me if I am wrong, I'm quite new to Haskell. Following the Reddit link I posted in the question, the commenter seems to think that that is not enough for proof. That is also why I have asked for a clarification. I would also appreciate it if you could answer the other queries. Thanks!

Comment: How is that any different than, e.g., using `primTrustMe` in Agda?

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I do not know Agda/Idris/Coq, I was merely asking a question about them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If somebody recommended that you do in proofs *in Haskell*, ask for your money back. (But be sure to double check you understood. Maybe they said to do proofs *about Haskell* and your memory is bad!)

You are correct: it is not very good for checking proofs. Haskell is, as a logic, inconsistent. That means you can prove anything. There's a quote from another smart Haskeller that I think of from time to time; I can't find the exact wording, but it goes something like "programmers are logicians that spend all their time proving trivial theorems in overly complicated ways". This is just another example of that; a real logician, once they found an inconsistency, would stop trying to prove other things because they've already finished proving everything.

The languages you mention (Coq, Agda, and Idris) get around this problem by requiring not just a proof of the thing you want to prove, but also a proof *that the proof you wrote finishes evaluating eventually*. (Mostly that second proof is implicitly enforced by restricting the class of proofs you can write, but people are extending the class of proofs that pass the automatic checks all the time.) Once you demand termination, it is no longer possible to implement `error :: String -> a` in the first place. (Except as a compiler primitive, of course... so they just don't do that.)

Comment: That makes so much sense! Just for clarification, using stuff like `Maybe` is still fine or not?

Comment: @NaitikMundra `Maybe` is great. I use `Maybe` all the time. I used a little `Maybe` with breakfast this morning, and sometimes I like a little afternoon uncertainty to brighten my day. (In case it wasn't obvious, I have no idea what you're actually asking.)

Comment: I meant the keywork used to return optionally, for eg with `Just`. In haskell: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe. I thought that considering this would always terminate, it would be fine to write in a proof.

Comment: So if I had a function that returned `Maybe`, I could still formally verify it?

Comment: @NaitikMundra Returning a `Maybe` does not make a function significantly harder to formally verify. But I once again find your question a bit strange and am unsure I've understood it. For example, "still verify" implies you are changing an existing formally verified function. What did it used to do, and what does it do now instead? What tool did you use to formally verify its correctness? What changed about the spec that you are verifying it against? All of these matter much more than its type does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still new to the world of formal proofs and functional programming and all. I will try to make better and more specific questions next time, once I have better knowledge.